# Prism modularity: What is moduleType (and moduleName)?

Tags: wpf, configuration, module, prism

When setting up modules in a Prism / WPF, using

```
<section name="modules" type="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModulesConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Prism"
```

...there is a  section in the app.config file, where you can add each module, like this:

```
<module assemblyFile="MyCompany.ABC.Client.Module.OutlookBar.dll"
moduleType="MyCompany.ABC.Client.Module.OutlookBarModule.OutlookBarModule,     
MyCompany.ABC.Client.Module.OutlookBar" moduleName="OutlookBarModule" 
startupLoaded="true"/>
```

This code works, but I would really like to know more about the moduleType attribute. What does it consist of?

At first I thought it was namespace.classname + comma + namespace.
(that is the fully qualified class name, the namespace (without classname).

But the namespace surrounding the "main class" in my OutlookBar is named like this:
MyCompany.ABC.Client.Module.OutlookBarModule
and its classname is "OutlookBarModule".

So... what is the second part (after the comma) of the moduleType definition??? I can't find this name ("MyCompany.ABC.Client.Module.OutlookBar") in my code, other than in the assembly name.

Best regards,
Andreas

Comment: The header for my question indicated that I had a question regarding the moduleName as well, but I forgot to write the question. I found out on another place that "by default, the class name is used as the module name when a module name is not specified." That could be correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is the assembly name (without the file extension, which may be .exe or .dll).  This is a common pattern for referencing classes via configuration in .NET: "namespace.classname, assemblyname".

Comment: It seems it can be more than just the assembly name. I'm looking at a Module Catalog that specifies an IModule implementing class in the ModuleType attribute:  
ModuleType="MyProject.ModuleInit, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0"

Comment: Yes, but the part that the OP asked about is only the assembly name.  What you have there is Namespace.Classname, AssemblyName, Version

Answer (score 0):

Probably is what you say, the assembly name, as it is a fully qualified name omitting version, culture, ...

Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In Prism 4 the ModuleType attribute is the assembly-qualified name of a Type that implements IModule which is commonly a class called ModuleInit in each project

Prism's ModuleInitializer.cs shows the following:

```
protected virtual IModule CreateModule(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
{
    if (moduleInfo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("moduleInfo");

    //Below Prism is passing the ModuleType property
    return this.CreateModule(moduleInfo.ModuleType);
}

protected virtual IModule CreateModule(string typeName)
{
    Type moduleType = Type.GetType(typeName);
    if (moduleType == null)
    {
        throw new ModuleInitializeException(
            string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            Properties.Resources.FailedToGetType, typeName));
    }

    //and then that type is cast to IModule
    return (IModule)this.serviceLocator.GetInstance(moduleType);
}
```